# Move mercurial-server home and repo location

Tags: ubuntu-12.10, mercurial-server

How to move mercurial-server (hg) home directory from /etc/mercurial-server/ to different location.I would like to store keys and repo in different disk

In Ubuntu 12.10

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial-server
sudo usermod -d /SOURCE/mercurial-server -m hg
#copied public_key to ~hg/keys/root/username
sudo -u hg /usr/share/mercurial-server/refresh-auth
```

Home dir moved and updated in /etc/passwd

but refresh-auth still use /etc/mercurial-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/etc/mercurial-server should never be the home directory of mercurial-server; usually that's /var/lib/mercurial-server but you can move it.  /etc/mercurial-server contains some files that affect the behaviour of mercurial-server.  You can decide where that's located with  ~hg/.mercurial-server.

Comment: I confused /etc/mercurial-server/ with /var/lib/mercurial-server and copied public key to ~hg/keys/root instead of /etc/mercurial-server/keys/root/. Thanks